# I'd like to know vs I like to...why is it or isn't it correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I have this sentence:

**I like to know if the rumor is true or not.**

vs.

**I like to know if rumors are true or not.**

Since we are talking about likes, should 'rumor' be used in the plural tense, as we are speaking about rumors generally, or can both sentences be correct grammatically?

Could you explain explain the reasoning?

Comment: Both are grammatical. The question is whether they express what you intend and whether they express that well.

Comment: So plural and singular form of "rumor" in this sentence is both correct?

Comment: There is no *I'd* in your examples!!!

Answer (score 1):

"would" is missing out of both of those sentences.  You might hear this spoken as, "I like to know...", but it should be "i'd like to know..." or "I would like to know..."

when it's spoken, it should be "I'd like..." or "I would like..."

As for which one is correct, it depends on what you mean.

O -  **I'd** like to know if the rumor is true or not (this is correct, and is asking about one rumor, show they want to know if it's true or not true)

O  - **I'd** like to know if the rumor**s** **are** true or not (same as the example above, but about multiple rumors)

X  - **I'd** like to know if rumor**s** **are** true or not (this is technically correct, but probably not what you want to say.  it's not natural.  And means someone wants to know if any rumors about anything are correct.  It's too vague to understand the meaning.

Comment: When we speak of hypotheticals, we use "I'd". However, in this sentence, I'm writing as if I speaking about my personal preferences, for example:

"I like to visit amusement parks."
"I like to understand all the information before I make my final opinion."

Would you consider my original post incorrect? Should 'rumor' be plural or not in order for it to be correct?

Comment: @Nathalie As far as I can tell, you're just asking the same question again. Which has been answered here. Syntactically, both sentences are correct. But how many rumours are there? If one, then it's *rumour*; if more than one, then it's *rumours*. (You mention two: amusement parks and information. Given that you mention two, it would be *rumours*. Assuming that I'm asking about both of them. Or I could use *rumour*, and you could ask me which one I'm asking about.)

Comment: I'd like to know whether the rumors are true.  ("or not" is redundant)